# ¿Cómo puedo crear una aplicación Android que no se pueda cerrar así como WhatsApp?

Tags: android

¿Cómo hacer que mi aplicación no se pueda cerrar? Esto no quiere decir que no se pueda forzar detención.

Lo que vi es que WhatsApp no se puede cerrar al igual que otras apps,
siguen corriendo cuando le doy al botón rápido de cerrar aplicaciones.

Comment: esto te será de utilidad: https://developer.android.com/training/run-background-service/create-service.html

Answer (score 2):

Todas las aplicaciones se cierran, creo que tienes una falta de conocimiento del ciclo de vida de una aplicacion y de las activities, fragments, etc.

Te explico.

Las aplicaciones podemos decir que pueden tener 2 estados. Primer plano y segundo plano.

El primer plano es cuando la tienes abierta y la ves en tu pantalla.
Segundo plano es cuando no esta en pantalla y se ejecuta.

En el caso de whatsapp lo que sucede es que tienes un servicio que esta siempre a la espera de recibir una notificación(un mensaje, una llamada, etc)

Lo que necesitas es un servicio para que tu aplicación siempre este a la espera, crear un servicio es sencillo.

Esta es la definición sencilla de un IntentService que te puede service:

```
public class HelloIntentService extends IntentService {

  /**
   * A constructor is required, and must call the super IntentService(String)
   * constructor with a name for the worker thread.
   */
  public HelloIntentService() {
      super("HelloIntentService");
  }

  /**
   * The IntentService calls this method from the default worker thread with
   * the intent that started the service. When this method returns, IntentService
   * stops the service, as appropriate.
   */
  @Override
  protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
      // Normally we would do some work here, like download a file.
      // For our sample, we just sleep for 5 seconds.
      try {
          Thread.sleep(5000);
      } catch (InterruptedException e) {
          // Restore interrupt status.
          Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
      }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

En realidad Whatsapp se cierra, lo que sucede es que está en ejecución un servicio en segundo plano, puedes investigar un poco servicios y adaptadores para sincronización de datos en el siguiente link.

Servicios
https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html

Adaptadores
https://developer.android.com/training/sync-adapters/creating-sync-adapter.html